# Oracle sql week period addition issue

Tags: oracle

I have a week period stored in database, the week period is in VARCHAR2()

Example: 2014019
 it indicates the week 19 of year 2014

I want to do operation like add/minus on the week period, 2014019 + 1 will be 2014020

BUT, i cant do normal addition/subtraction because 2014052 (last week of 2014) + 1 = 2014053 which is wrong.

2014052 + 1 = 2015001 which is correct.

Any idea how to solve this problem with sql/store procedure?

Comment: Are you storing IW (ISO) or WW in week period column?

Comment: IW starts new week from each monday, WW starts from the first day of the year (each 7 days adds one week)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will always have the same length string (4 digit + '0' + 2 digit) then you can simply substring it out:
(Added Leap Year Logic)

```
DECLARE lvchInput   VARCHAR2(7);
        lvchOutput  VARCHAR2(7);
        lnYear      NUMBER;
        lnWeek      NUMBER;
        lbLeap      BOOLEAN;

BEGIN
    lvchInput := '2012052';
    lnYear := to_number(SubStr(lvchInput, 1, 4));
    lnWeek := to_number(SubStr(lvchInput, 6, 2));

    IF (Mod(lnYear, 4) = 0 AND Mod(lnYear, 100) <> 0) OR Mod(lnYear, 400) = 0 THEN
        lbLeap := TRUE;
    ELSE
        lbLeap := FALSE;
    END IF; 

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('lbLeap = ' || CASE WHEN lbLeap = TRUE THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('lnYear = ' || to_char(lnYear));
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('lnWeek = ' || to_char(lnWeek));

    IF (lbLeap AND lnWeek >= 53) OR 
       (NOT lbLeap AND lnWeek >= 52) THEN
        lnWeek := 0;
        lnYear := lnYear + 1;
    END IF;
    lnWeek := lnWeek + 1;

    lvchOutput := to_char(lnYear) || '0' || LPad(to_char(lnWeek), 2, '0');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('lvchOutput = ' || lvchOutput);
END;
```

Comment: You can, of course, convert this into a stored procedure or function which you can call in a query.

Comment: but it dont take care about the leap year and non leap year...like 2015 has 53 weeks, 2014 has 52 weeks

Comment: A simple google search found this: https://community.oracle.com/thread/1130019
There are a few good options to determin leap year in there.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Added leap year conditions as OP requested.

EDIT 2: Forgot to check if the new YEAR after YEAR:=YEAR+1 is a leap year. Added the condition and test case.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ADD_WEEK (p_date IN VARCHAR2, nrOfWeeks IN NUMBER)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
   RESULT       VARCHAR2 (8);
   YEAR         NUMBER;
   WEEK         NUMBER;
   LEAP_LIMIT   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   YEAR := SUBSTR (p_date, 1, 4);
   WEEK := SUBSTR (p_date, 6, 2);

   IF (MOD (YEAR, 400) = 0)
   THEN
      LEAP_LIMIT := 54;
   ELSIF (MOD (YEAR, 100) = 0)
   THEN
      LEAP_LIMIT := 53;
   ELSIF (MOD (YEAR, 4) = 0)
   THEN
      LEAP_LIMIT := 54;
   ELSE
      LEAP_LIMIT := 53;
   END IF;

   FOR i IN 1 .. nrOfWeeks
   LOOP
      WEEK := WEEK + 1;

      IF WEEK >= LEAP_LIMIT
      THEN
         WEEK := 1;
         YEAR := YEAR + 1;
      END IF;

   --check if the resulted year is a leap year before reentering the loop
   IF (MOD (YEAR, 400) = 0)
   THEN
      LEAP_LIMIT := 54;
   ELSIF (MOD (YEAR, 100) = 0)
   THEN
      LEAP_LIMIT := 53;
   ELSIF (MOD (YEAR, 4) = 0)
   THEN
      LEAP_LIMIT := 54;
   ELSE
      LEAP_LIMIT := 53;
   END IF;  

   END LOOP;

   RESULT :=
         YEAR
      || '0'
      || (CASE
             WHEN week < 10 THEN '0' || TO_CHAR (week)
             ELSE TO_CHAR (week)
          END);
   RETURN RESULT;
END ADD_WEEK;
```

Can be called with for example (add as many weeks as you want)

```
 select  ADD_WEEK('2014052',2) AS RESULT from dual
```

produces result of

```
2015002
```

for a leap year

```
select  ADD_WEEK('2012052',1) AS RESULT from dual
```

output:

```
2012053
```

adding many weeks and keeping track of leap years

```
2012 -53
2013 -52
2014 -52
2015 -52
total of 53+3*52=209 weeks, should give result of 2016001 if starting from 2012001

select  ADD_WEEK('2012001',209) AS RESULT from dual
```

and result is:

```
2016001
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace function add_weeks(f_week_period in varchar2, f_weeks_to_add NUMBER, f_fmt varchar2) return varchar2 as 
  l_year  integer;
  l_weeks integer;
  l_last  integer;
begin
  l_year := to_number(substr(f_week_period, 1, 4));
  l_weeks := to_number(substr(f_week_period, -2, 2)) + f_weeks_to_add;

  while true loop
    -- get the max number of weeks in the year
    l_last := to_number(to_char(to_date(l_year || '1231', 'YYYYMMDD'), f_fmt));
    -- IW can return 1
    if l_last = 1 then
      l_last := to_number(to_char(to_date(l_year || '1224', 'YYYYMMDD'), f_fmt));  
    end if;
    if (l_last >= l_weeks) then
      exit;
    else 
      l_weeks := l_weeks - l_last;
      l_year := l_year + 1;
    end if;
  end loop;
  return l_year || '0' || l_weeks;  
end add_weeks;
```

Usage:

```
-- ISO weeks
select add_weeks('2014019', 50, 'IW') from dual;

-- WW weeks
select add_weeks('2014019', 50, 'WW') from dual;
```

Function works only with positive `f_weeks_to_add` (but it's not difficult to modify it to work with negative).

`f_fmt` can take 'WW' or 'IW'